# ionic text to speech not working on browser

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement text-to speech in my ionic application and use cordova-plugin-tts and add it with: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-tts`
Here is my code:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.speakText = function() {
   window.TTS.speak({
       text: 'hello',
       locale: 'en-GB',
       rate: 1.5
   }, function () {
       // Do Something after success
   }, function (reason) {
       // Handle the error case
   });
};
```

I run it with `ionic serve`.When I call this function, the console says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'speak' of undefined`.Should I add module name or something after `$scope` in controller?

Comment: could you check `window.TTS` object is available..  it seems that `cordova-plugin-tts` haven't loaded correctly..

Comment: it says 'undifined', how to make it available?

Comment: sorry, i'm new to this

Comment: @Alasry you may have to register deviceready event listener and invoke plugin code inside the listener to ensure that the plugin is loaded completely

Comment: Plugins don't work in browser.

Answer (score 3):

yes, it's very simple and important task for TTS. as you know `Cordova` have a plugin for it and I was wonder after meet this plugin. to use this plugin you have to follow these simple steps :

**1 - add Cordova plugin**

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/macdonst/SpeechRecognitionPlugin
```

**2 - add TTS plugin**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-tts
```

**3- implementation of plugin code**

```
  app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    speechText: ''
  };
  $scope.recognizedText = '';

  $scope.speakText = function() {
    window.TTS.speak({
           text: $scope.data.speechText,
           locale: 'en-GB',
           rate: 0.7
       }, function () {
           // Do Something after success
       }, function (reason) {
           // Handle the error case
        alert(reason+"");
       });
  };

  $scope.record = function() {
    var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
        if (event.results.length > 0) {
            $scope.recognizedText = event.results[0][0].transcript;
            $scope.$apply()
        }
    };
    recognition.start();
  };
});
```

for more information about this you can visit this [site](http://devgirl.org/2016/01/08/speaking-with-cordova/)
 enjoy your code time:)

Answer (score -1):

For implementing native features such as camera, tts etc . we need to run/test the application on the devices whether it is android or ios.
so build the app on your device. 
First, add platform by command: **ionic cordova platform add android**

connect your device to your laptop and run the command:  **cordova run android**

I hope it will work.